# Start count from zero on each keypress

Tags: c++, algorithm, events

I have a program in which I am drawing images on the screen. The draw function here is called per frame inside in which I have all my drawing code.

I have written an image sequencer that return the respective image from an index of images.

```
void draw()
{
sequence.getFrameForTime(getCurrentElapsedTime()).draw(0,0); //get current time returns time in float and startson application start
}
```

On key press, I have start the sequences from the first image [0] and then go on further. So, everytime I press a key, it has to start from [0] unlike the above code where it basically uses the currentTime%numImages to get the frame (which is not the start 0 position of image).

I was thinking to write a timer of own that basically can be triggered everytime I press the key so that the time always starts from 0. But before doing that, I wanted to ask if anybody had better/easier implementation ideas for this?

EDIT
Why I didn't use just a counter?
I have framerate adjustments in my ImageSequence as well.

```
Image getFrameAtPercent(float rate)
{
float totalTime = sequence.size() / frameRate;
float percent = time / totalTime;
return setFrameAtPercent(percent);
}

int getFrameIndexAtPercent(float percent){
if (percent < 0.0 || percent > 1.0) percent -= floor(percent);
    return MIN((int)(percent*sequence.size()), sequence.size()-1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
void draw()
{
    sequence.getFrameForTime(counter++).draw(0,0); 
}

void OnKeyPress(){ counter = 0; }
```

Is there a reason this wont suffice?

Comment: Editted the question and added detail about this. If I use the counter, the counter would be incremented as per the applications global frame rate. I wouldn't have control over the frame rate of the increments to get the sequencer working.

Comment: @user1240679 In that case you can either increment differently as emartel suggests, or convert counter count to frame # in some function similar to `getFrameForTime` or as you say implement your own counter class which encapulates these details.

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is increase a "currentFrame" as a `float` and convert it to an `int` to index your frame:

```
void draw()
{
    currentFrame += deltaTime * framesPerSecond; // delta time being the time between the current frame and your last frame
    if(currentFrame >= numImages)
        currentFrame -= numImages;
    sequence.getFrameAt((int)currentFrame).draw(0,0);
}

void OnKeyPress() { currentFrame = 0; }
```

This should gracefully handle machines with different framerates and even changes of framerates on a single machine.

Also, you won't be skipping part of a frame when you loop over as the remainder of the substraction is kept.